# Unable to copy data to SQL server - "There is already an object named in the database."

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got a table in a legacy non-sql program that has a routine to copy the data into a SQL Server database. The developer of this system wrote the routine with no documentation to see what is happening under the hood. One table I attempted to move ended up failing, now when I try to copy this table over I get the following error:

> Unable to create table 'CR_Receipt_Payment_Details'
>
> 42S01: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] There is
>   already an object named 'byReceipt_RECPMT' in the database.

I know that I need to delete this object so that the process can run. I tried running

```
Drop Table byReceipt_RECPMT
```

and have the following output:

> Cannot use DROP TABLE with 'byReceipt_RECPMT' because 'byReceipt_RECPMT' is a constraint. Use ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Can someone point me in the direction of how to find and drop this object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table already exists, then you want to do this:

```
ALTER TABLE CR_Receipt_Payment_Details DROP CONSTRAINT byReceipt_RECPMT
```

However, the problem may be that there is a constraint with that name on a DIFFERENT table. You need to find out what table that is. Or else, rename the constraint for THIS table.

Answer (score 1):

This means that your database has a constraint (primary key, foreign key, check, etc.) named `byReceipt_RECPMT`. Because that name is being used by a constraint, it can't be used by a table.

You *could* drop the constraint, but so far the only reason you have is that you want to use its name for a table. That's not good enough. If you investigate the constraint and find that it's incorrect or that you don't need it, by all means drop it - Ross Presser's answer shows how to do so.

If you do need the constraint, either rename the constraint or use a different table name. To rename a constraint, use the `sp_rename` system stored procedure:

```
sp_rename 'CR_Receipt_Payment_Details.byReceipt_RECPMT', 'new constraint name'
```

[`sp_rename` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) (There are examples in the section titled "Renaming constraints").